# How to close browser based alert using selenium web

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to close browser-based alert using selenium. This is closed by below robot class code. But any other way to close this alert message.

```
  Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(3000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

[image: Browser based alert/popup]

Comment: This alert is different compare to mentioned in the above link. Here Allow or Dismiss button is displayed. Moreover the above code is not closing that alert window. Please suggest any other method to solve the above issue.

Comment: for Firefox: options.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);  for Chrome:  prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

Comment: Tried this comment.Not working it out.Tried with option 1 also. Used below code. Please suggest any other way to hide this option please. Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);   
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);.

Comment: that looks correct, or you initializing the driver like this?: driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: another option might be setting unhandledPromptBehavior... though not sure if it'll handle this... use:  UnexpectedAlertBehaviour promptBehaviorConstant = UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.DISMISS; options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(promptBehaviorConstant);  This will be triggered on the next action.  (if an unhandled prompt is open, the driver will dismiss it.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the browser option -

`options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");`

Comment: The above robot class is working fine. But looking at alternative solutions because the above code is failing if we are opened any other window is opened while executing this code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an alert, shouldn't work as a basic one?

Use driver's methods:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();  or  driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: I have added the image for this alert in top. I guess this is browser-based notification window. The basic above comment is not working. But robot class is only working. Looking for an alternative code.